# How to generate id in android randomly and programmatically?

Tags: android, android-view, android-identifiers

I'm trying to generate random ids for views as shown in following screenshot.
But it didn't work. It got null.
How should I findViewById ?

[image]

Comment: You're confused. `setID` and `findViewByID` both are different. `findViewByID` allows you to refer to the particular view with the id you give in the xml file.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this. This is a wrong thing to do. I mean when you create a view you give it an id then how can you expect to access that view by generating some random id.

Comment: So.., what am I supposed to do to get back textView ?

Comment: @Sar009 , cuz I've to create a lot views dynamically and got to reuse them from somewhere in the project.

Comment: why not try ListView when you have to create a LOT OF views dynamically.

Comment: I can't use ListView. Cuz my views depends on JSON from server. I don't predict what will be coming.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use `textView.setId(View.generateViewId())` introduced in API 17.

Answer (score 4):

Best practices for unique identifiers

Java

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Kotlin

```
var uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

This means you're creating the TextView dynamically. So you don't need to do `findViewById`. 
`findViewById` is used when the view with id is present in xml file.

Remove the `TextView cloneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(randomNo)` line. Your question is vague, I tried to explain.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I made TextView tv = new TextView(this). How can I call it from another activity without knowing id? Don't say to make static. My views will be create dynamically so there's no static.

Comment: You want the value of that `TextView`? If so, you can pass the value using Intent.

Answer (score 0):

I got my own solution...
It should be like that..

```
Random r = new Random();
    randomNo = r.nextInt(1000+1);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(randomNo);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<childCount;i++){
        if(linearLayout.getChildAt(i).getId()==randomNo){
            TextView cloneTextView = (TextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            cloneTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            cloneTextView.setText("I'm a clone...!");
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            linearLayout.addView(cloneTextView);
        }
    }
```

It works and that's what I want. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work.

But I'm not sure about possible performance and memory issues, since it will return an instance of a view (if found). During a little test sequence it never hit an existing id, with other words the first random number was always ok.

```
private int createUniqueId() {

    int id = RandomUtils.nextInt();

    while(findViewById(id) != null) {
        //id is not unique, try another one...
        id = RandomUtils.nextInt();
    }
    //return unique id
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create UUID (universal unique identifier)   as follow :

```
String id= UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: While code-only answer are allowed on Stack Overflow, it's always better to include a brief explanation, so that other users will understand it faster and better :)

Comment: widgets ids are numbers not strings nor hex values